# D* / D* Lite query (dynamic pathfinding algorithms)

Tags: dynamic, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

I'm writing a paper comparing D*, D* Lite and LPA* and how useful they are in navigating an agent across a dynamic environment.

If anyone has any info that would be helpful for this please leave below.

Specifically, can anyone explain in simple terms why D* and D* lite traverse from goal to start rather than start to goal like LPA*? I understand the g value would then be the distance from the goal but confused as to what benefits this has.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you search outwards from the start state, all of the outward paths also give you routes back to the start, making it easy to get back there. Then, when you get to the goal, you have one path to the goal, but many paths from other states back to the start.

If the world isn't changing it doesn't matter whether you search backwards or forwards (or bidirectionally), in the end you have a path that you can use.

But, if the world changes and you lose your one path to the goal from a forward search, it can be hard to re-connect to that single path. If instead you search outwards from the goal, you still have many paths back to the goal. If the world changes, you can then search to reconnect the invalidated states back to any path that leads to the goal (of which there are many). Although it may not be optimal, it may only require a small and simple repair.